# How to select an element just once in plain SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I've seen other similar questions to mine, but I haven't found one that could actually help me. I have a table, defined like so:

```
CREATE TABLE "DOWNLOAD_HISTORY" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 344 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "IDUSER" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "IDFORNITORE" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "IDRFX" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DOCNUM" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DOWNLOAD_TIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL ENABLE
   ) ;
```

This DDL comes from an OracleDB12 database. 
Following, some sample data

[image]

*What I'd like to accomplish*: if there's already a row with the same tuple (IDRFX, DOCNUM), not including it in the SELECT statement. So, the tuple (384,1) should appear only once.

*What I've done (so far)*: with the idea that this query could be performed even from a MSSQL database, I've tried to write these two queries in plain SQL.

```
SELECT * 
FROM DOWNLOAD_HISTORY dh 
WHERE dh.IDRFX = 384 AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM DOWNLOAD_HISTORY dh2 WHERE dh.DOCNUM <> dh2.DOCNUM AND dh.IDRFX <> dh2.IDRFX )



SELECT t1.*
FROM DOWNLOAD_HISTORY t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from DOWNLOAD_HISTORY t2
                  where t2.DOCNUM = t1.DOCNUM 
                    and t2.IDRFX = t1.IDRFX)
```

But none of them was actually able to get me anywhere. If possible, I'd like to ask where am I doing the mistake and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number` analytical function as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT t1.*, row_number() over (partition by t1.DOCNUM, t1.IDRFX order by 1) as rn
FROM DOWNLOAD_HISTORY t1)
WHERE RN = 1;
```

OR you can use the `NOT EXISTS` query as follows:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM DOWNLOAD_HISTORY t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from DOWNLOAD_HISTORY t2
                  where t2.DOCNUM = t1.DOCNUM 
                    and t2.IDRFX = t1.IDRFX
                    and t2.ID > t1.ID); -- add only this condition in your query
```

Comment: I didn't possibly think of adding the last AND CLAUSE to the NOT EXIST query! Thank you, this solved my problem and in plain SQL!

Comment: Out of curiosity: in terms of performances, which is better?

Comment: NOT EXISTS is good for performance but in oracle, Many changes are done after Oracle 11g and the Analytical function is also faster in Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

Without analytic functions....

```
    with data as(
select 1 id, 384 idrfx, 1 docnum from dual union all
select 2 id, 384 idrfx, 1 docnum from dual union all
select 3 id, 384 idrfx, 2 docnum from dual union all
select 4 id, 385 idrfx, 1 docnum from dual 
)
,uniqueTuple as  (
select min(id) id from data
group by idrfx,docnum 
)

select d.* 
from data d
join uniqueTuple u on u.id = d.id
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use subquery with `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.DOCNUM,IDRFX ORDER BY t.ID) RN
    FROM DOWNLOAD_HISTORY t
) SQ
WHERE SQ.RN = 1;
```

Comment: Is ROW_NUMBER() a standard SQL function or peculiar to MSSQL and ORACLE?

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() is a standard  window function. It is available in almost all of the DBMS (_latest versions_)

Answer (score 0):

I guess your answer doens't work because DOWNLOAD_TIMESTAMP is unique. Only the Columns IDUSER, IDFORNITORE, IDRFX and IDRFX seem to contain the same tuples multiple times.

So either you do a SELECT DISTINCT on the Columns that really should be distinct (so no ID or DOWNLOAD_TIMESTAMP) or you adjust the superquery in your WHERE Not exist and change the SELECT * to SELECT and then only the Columns where you want to have unique Tuples.

So this would be the easiest solution for me.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
IDUSER, 
IDFORNITORE, 
IDRFX, 
IDRFX
FROM Database
```

Comment: Close! The only problem is that I must return the download_timestamp, so this solves only for a 75% the problem :(

Comment: But than your tuples are not unique anymore.

How to you determine the download_timestamp for a given tuple?

If you want the min or max value of the download_timestamp for a given tuple you could just JOIN the table on itself and add the download_timestamp to a tuple this way.

Comment: It's a information that is determined at runtime by the system. When the system executes this query, it also needs to display the download_timestamp